# Quickest way to set many variables with similar names and values in PHP

Tags: php, shortcut

I want to set 26 "counters", one for each letter of the alphabet. They have similar names, and they all start with a value of 0. There has to be a faster way to do this. Here's the code:

```
$a_count = 0;
$b_count = 0;
$c_count = 0;
$d_count = 0;
$e_count = 0;
$f_count = 0;
$g_count = 0;
$h_count = 0;
$a_count = 0;
$i_count = 0;
$j_count = 0;
$k_count = 0;
$l_count = 0;
$m_count = 0;
$n_count = 0;
$o_count = 0;
$p_count = 0;
$q_count = 0;
$r_count = 0;
$s_count = 0;
$t_count = 0;
$u_count = 0;
$v_count = 0;
$w_count = 0;
$x_count = 0;
$y_count = 0;
$z_count = 0;
```

How do I do this without taking up 26 lines?

Comment: I'd recommend using an array for this really.

Comment: Maybe explain what you want to do with those variables later.

Comment: Is there a file and/or a database involved? Or other source? It's worth knowing.

Comment: It'd be nice if I could change my vote to close from "Too broad" to "Unclear", because at this point, it's just *that*.

Comment: @funkfortyniner I don't understand what's unclear here, I gave a perfectly clear code snippet. The question is exactly what I asked, nothing else is important. Not to mention, I got a great answer pretty much immediately so it can't be that unclear.

Comment: @nomadofnowhere313 I asked for clarification about its source, and not (more) code. That's why it was unclear for me. There could have been more answers given that would have probably given a different and possibly faster approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array instead. It will make your code a **lot** simpler in the long run.

```
$counts = array_fill_keys(range('a', 'z'), 0);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/SeKhk)